# How to reload page in cakephp using jQuery when clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0

In my program i want to reload the page when clicking the comment button. What exactly happens is it do update the data in my database but i have to manually reload rather i want to reload page as soon as i click comment button.

```
     echo $this->Js->submit('Comment', 
                        array(
                            'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
                            'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),

                            //'before'=>'alert("Comment posted");',
                            //'success'=>'jQuery("#PostComment").val("");',
                            'url' => array(
                                'controller' => 'posts',
                                'action' => 'comment/'.$post['Post']['id']
                            ),
                            'update' => '#UserComment',
                            //'class'=>'submit',
                            'class' => 'comment',
                            'id'=>'SubmitComment',

                        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just redirect to the same page after clicking the comment button

return $this->redirect($this->here); OR

return $this->redirect($this->request->here); // cake 2.x

> suppose we have a function handling comment inside your controller

```
public function comment() {
   // process content here...

   // redirects the user immediately with a nice message
   $this->flash('Your comment has been saved, thanks', '<page you wish to redirect');

   OR

   $this->setFlash('blablablabla');
   return $this->redirect($this->here); // this->here refers to the current pageurl
      OR
   return $this->redirect($this->request->here); // cake 2.x (// this->request->here refers to the current pageurl)


}
```

Comment: Yeah i thank you for this but what i want is when it is complete i want to reload is their any option?

Comment: Currently what happens on comment button click.

Comment: Change your button to this.
echo $this->Html->link('Comment', '/redirect/url', array('class' => 'button')); 
This way you can redirect to comment function .